# what's the function of parantheses in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I know most of people using the following script like

```
(function(){})();
```

for anonymous function call. But what's the function of the surrounding parantheses?

```
var g = (); // syntax error, why?
var g= (function(){}); // correct
```

Can anybody explain it for me?

Comment: var g=(444);(1+45589); //works and typeof(g) is number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`()` is used for several things within JavaScript.

#### Method invocation

When used as an operator, it'll be used to call a function, optionally with a list of parameters:

```
var a = function() { console.log(23); }
a() // => 23
```

You can see this, when people use anonymous functions which are called directly to create closures. just as in your example:

```
(function(){})();
```

Although i guess most people would write it this way:

```
(function(){}());
```

to indicate, that the function is grouped and the expression is part of a whole. This leads to another use case:

#### Grouping an expression

`()` can be used to group expressions. Like this:

```
(1,2,3);
```

The empty `()` would be a syntax error. But this would work:

```
a = (1,2,3);
console.log(a); // => 3
```

It's the case in your example:

```
var g = (function(){});
```

`g` has been assigned an anonymous function as it's value. This would also work:

```
var g = function() {};
```

Same effect.

Grouping has no immediate value, but when you consider creating anonymous functions for closures, it is pretty essential:

```
function() {
    // your code
}(); // => Syntax Error
```

But this will work:

```
(function() {
    return 12;
}());
```

as the expression is grouped.

Answer (score 5):

`()` is used to **group an expression**. When there is no expression inside, its a syntax error.

To illustrate it, see the following example.

```
var x = 5; // works
var y = (5); // works
var z = (); // syntax error!
```

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses around the function expression is to make it an expression.

The syntax of a named function is too similar for a function expression to work without the parentheses in that case:

```
function(){}();
        ^
        |______ syntax error, function name expected
```

In other cases where a function expression is used, it's already known that it has to be an expression, for example:

```
var f = function(){};
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `(function(){})();`. This is a Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE). This is a very popular pattern used to avoid collisions. See [this article](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).
2. `var g= (function(){})`. This is an effective varible assignment. In fact, after executing this statement, the g variables contains the function. Let's try this:

   ```
     var g = (function(){console.log('hello')});
     g();
   ```
3. `var g = ();`. This is not a valid syntax for the language specification. See the [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) for further details.